# Django: how to define a one-to-one relationship to a table in admin?

Tags: django

Good day, friends!

I am trying to define a one-to-one relationship to an user in django admin. Below is my code in models.py in an app:

```
from django.db import models

class Tutor(models.Model):
    account = models.OneToOneField([A User from Admin]) # what should I code here?
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

What should I write instead of [A User from Admin]?

Thanks.

Comment: It really depends how you set up your User model. Are you just using the Django default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
#You need to add the aforementioned line if you want to load User model here

class Tutor(models.Model):
    account = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Now if you want to access it by user info then you can. Say, you need to access a user's first_name. Then you will just run the relationship query here:

```
user_info = User.objects.get(username='someone')
first_name = user_info.tutor.first_name
```

Additional information: If you need to add first_name and last_name for User you do not need to add another table. Just extends the **UserCreationForm** and add additional field for User Model.

Comment: Should you perhaps use `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` instead of `User`? via https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model

Comment: @getup8, Yes, we should use it. Sometime programmer knows that this project will not use any custom user model. That's why we use it directly. But what you said, that is the best practice.

Answer (score 1):

The user model belongs to `django.contrib.auth`

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class Tutor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

**Edit**

Like stated in the comments its better to reference the model via the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting. This way the code doesn't break if you change the user model. [Django Docs - Referencing the User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model)

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class Tutor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Comment: Same comment.. should you perhaps use `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` instead of `User`? via https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model